# Playstore install app crashing, but direct android studio install runs well

Tags: android, sqlite, crash

My app display questions from database. The database is initially in the assets folder
but copied internally on first run.
However the error i am getting from playstore install is that the table does not exists. 
I am not sure whats going on as the app perfectly runs on android studio with both actual device and emulator both.

Comment: Check logcat after install from play store. You can see log even you run app which is download from play store.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did check the logcat, thats how i found out the table not found error.

Comment: Now try to solve that error

Comment: The error just does not make any sense. i have extracted the database from the playstore download app, checked that it do have that table and also the direct install from android studio works well.

Comment: Do one thing..Generate signed APK from studio and then check in real device and let me know the result

Comment: Maybe need to add some progaurd,if you added some of libararies,i had this problem in my latest app

Comment: Can you tell me OS version in which you got crash ? And you copy db from assest folder  ?

Comment: @RahulArora yes if i install apk with from studio. it works well too